# Species Identification : What insect is this?

Tags: species-identification

I noticed this insect in the end of last December on the window of my room in Pune, India. There are at least 15 such insects on this window and 12 on another. None of these have moved even a millimeter since I first noticed them. They don't move even when the window is lightly banged. They are almost 1 to 1.5 cm in length and their tails have two ends. They are almost transparent.
Imgs:
[image: 1.]
[image: 2. Side view]
[image: 3.]

Comment: I know that it is a Mayfly (Ephemperoptera), but I am not familiar with the mayfly families in India. The reduced wings on this individual are unusual.

Comment: More properly, this _was_ a mayfly; it is a castoff exoskeleton from either a last-instar naiad or a subimago; many mayfly groups have only two caudal filaments as seen here, so while that detail will help in the eventual identification, it cannot be used on its own.